# Activity 1 calls Activity 2 and get string result from Activity 2

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am passing a putextra from first activity to second activity. I validate what was passed to second activity. I have this working like I intended. My question is how to pass a string value back to the first activity.

Here is where I call the second activity from first.

```
public void scannedItem(String barCode,String localArea){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,selectItemActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Barcode",mScan);
    intent.putExtra("Area",myArea);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
   // finish();
}
```

On second activity I am receiving data from first activity like so

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_item);
    passedArea = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Area");
    passedScan=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Barcode");

    updateScreen();
}
```

I perform validation on the extras passed from first activity and would like to pass a single string back to the first activity. On second activity I have loaded a RecyclerViewer and on the onClick I have tried.

```
    public void onSelectClick(View view){
        String lSelectLocation = mLocations.getLocation();
        Timber.d(lSelectLocation);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("Location",lSelectLocation);
        finish();
    }
```

My question is at least two parts. 
1.) what do I have wrong on second activity to pass the String value back.
2.) On first activity what is needed to receive the String back. I have tried onResume but the following is null.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final String sender=this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("Location");
    if(sender != null)
    {
        this.receiveData();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

I also have this method on first activity but it doesn't seem to get fired.

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,String requestLocation,Intent data){
        mLoc.setText(requestLocation);
    }

I have learned a lot in the last few months in Java. I have years as VB.net programmer and sometimes get lost in the differences.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: please refer below answer and check

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult()` and put your `String` as an "extra" into an `Intent` that you send back in `setResult()`. The originating `Activity` gets the result in the `onActivityResult()` callback.

Comment: The method `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,String requestLocation,Intent data)` doesn't get called because it isn't an overriding method. You should use your IDE to help generate signatures for overriding methods and also you should use the `@Override` annotation. This would have warned you that the method has the wrong signature. That's why it isn't being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `getIntent();` in onSelectClick method with `new Intent();` and also define `setResult` as it will Call this to set the result that your activity will return to its caller.

```
public void onSelectClick(View view){
    String lSelectLocation = mLocations.getLocation();
    Timber.d(lSelectLocation);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Location",lSelectLocation);
    setResult(1, intent);
    finish();
}
```

and in first activity use `onActivityResult` to get the return value from second activity, not in `onResume`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == 1) {

        String str_location = null;
        if (data != null) {
            str_location = data.getStringExtra("Location");
            if (str_location != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str_location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: public void onSelectClick(View view){
    String lSelectLocation = mLocations.getLocation();
    Timber.d(lSelectLocation);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Location",lSelectLocation);
    setResult(1, intent);
    finish();
}

Comment: on the OnSelectClick lSelectLocation has expected value during the intent.putExtra bu during the onActivityResult data says has extras but str_location gets set to null. Also resultCode coming back as -1

Answer (score 0):

Use [setResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int)) in Activity 2 and the in Activity 1 get the values in onActivityResult....

Comment: startActivityForResult only asks for requestCode which seems to expect integer coming back. I need a String coming back